# How to clear the clogged washbasin?

Tags: bathroom, bathroom-fixtures

The washbasin in my bathroom is clogged very badly and I have no idea how can I clear it. I'm in Germany and their systems are very new to me and I don't even know what I should do on my own. Back home it was pretty simple and cheap to clear/replace the plastic pipes. Following is the pic of my basin:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Could you suggest what I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be debris in the popup drain assembly, or the trap (U-bend at the bottom) may be clogged, or there may be a problem downstream.

First, try a toilet plunger. Fill the basin halfway and give it a go.

If that doesn't do it, remove the white nut at the back of the drain tailpiece and pull out the lever. Now you can lift the popup drain plug out and see what's what. Here's what that system looks like:

[image]

When you reassemble it be sure to engage the loop in the drain plug. Don't over-tighten the plastic parts.

If you still don't have good flow, disassemble the trap using a rubber jar opener for grip and clear it. Turn the nuts counter-clockwise looking from the side with the rounded edges. If necessary, a slip-lock or locking pliers will help, but protect the chrome with a rag.

Comment: If you have to remove the trap, put a small bucket under it because it will be full of not so clean water.

Comment: If you are using a plunger and the sink has an overflow hole, hold a wet rag over the hole.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just removed the gasket/drain plug without having to remove the nut. I just pulled it out. It wasn't assembled before I think. Attached the pic as well. Do I need to disassemble the trap now or is there any ready made drain cleaner/remover/acid etc? I'm just not used to doing these repairs and I'm afraid I might damage them.

Comment: @DashingBoy You won't do any damage as long as you take care when screwing the connectors back on. They should only be done up hand-tight. A damp cloth can help sometimes if you need more grip. Don't use the sink to clean out the trap(!).

Comment: You're more likely to damage things with drain cleaner (acid). That stuff strips chrome. It also does a poor job of actually clearing the clog, since it runs out as soon as there's a small opening. I prefer mechanical cleaning.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification.